# iOS 11 list all applications

Tags: ios, ios11, iphone-privateapi

Is it possible to get a list of all installed applications in iOS 11 beta?

I'm working on enterprise application, so I'm able to use any private API.
I know about old methods, such as using LSApplicationWorkspace class, but it's not working in iOS 11.

Maybe I need to add some strings in entitlement file? Or something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In enterprise you can use Apple Mobile Device Management (MDM) Protocol ManagedApplicationList commands to get managed applications list

Comment: could you please describe more about this solution. My company is also using Apple Enterprise Account to distribute app in local network. We need to know applications which are installed in member's device. Many thanks.